# createComponent with custom CSS class

Tags: angular

```
   async getAlbum() {
    const { AlbumComponent } = await import("./album/album.component");
    this.viewContainer.createComponent(AlbumComponent);
  }
```

I do have a working function to load a standalone component (Angular 15).
I would like to add a CSS class dynamically to my viewContainer - for example class='fade'.  Basically, I would like to have the AlbumComponent fade in after it has been created.  to add class 'fade' in the AlbumComponent is NOT an option for me.
Anyone?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewContainerRef.createComponent` method returns [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) instance

which contains reference to component's host through `location` property

So here's your puzzle:

```
async getAlbum() {
  const { AlbumComponent } = await import("src/app/album/album.component");
  // this.viewContainer.createComponent(AlbumComponent);
  const componentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(AlbumComponent);
  componentRef.location.nativeElement.classList.add('fade', 'show');
}
```

Comment: That isn't working.  Please review my tiny example in my repos https://github.com/d052057/lazycomponent.  The fade class is in style.css.

Comment: You're creating component twice. Please see the full code of getAlbum methos

Comment: Thank you.  You have pinpointed or corrected my code.  'fade' is a class name defined in bootstrap. 1. When I defined or created 'fade' class, it executed the one from bootstrap.  2. I created component twice that another issue.  Yous code works well by using 'fade' from bootstrap.  Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: @yurzui, hey man, where did you dissappear?